# Date is not popping up when the button is press

Tags: android, datepicker

i'm new to android coding. I'm trying to set a date by clicking a button. i have read up and try lots of method posted by other members here but whenever i click on the button,nothing happen. Is there anything wrong with my code?

> public class Date extends Activity {

```
private TextView tvDisplayDate;
private Button btnDate;

private int year;
private int month;
private int day;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setCurrentDateOnView();
    addListenerOnButton();

}

// display current date
public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

    tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
    //dpResult = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpResult);

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // set current date into textview
    tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
        // Month is 0 based, just add 1
        .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
        .append(year).append(" "));



}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    btnDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SetDate);

    btnDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

        }

    });

}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
       // set date picker as current date
       return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, 
                     year, month,day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener 
            = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;

        // set selected date into textview
        tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
           .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
           .append(" "));


    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed use the Calender class however I rather keep it short and simpler with the same results. I'm going to show you an alternative I used and found on someone else his blog.

```
// Formats are everywhere on the internet.
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy ");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String output = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(output);
```

Simply change System.out.print method in to setText of your view.

Source: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-get-current-date-time-date-and-calender/

Comment: Thanks for the help, the code is easy to understand. i can get it working now :)